# Discuss $\mathbb R[X]/(aX^2 +bX + c)$ in terms of $\Delta = b^2-4ac$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials, quotient-group

> Discuss $\mathbb R[X]/(aX^2 +bX + c)$ in terms of $\Delta = b^2-4ac$.

I've already found that $\mathbb R[X]/(aX^2 +bX + c) \simeq \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ if $\Delta > 0$ and $\mathbb R[X]/(aX^2 +bX + c) \simeq \mathbb{C}$ if $\Delta < 0$.

For the case $\Delta = 0$ I don't really find an suitable morphism. The polynomial has only one root of multiplicity $2$ and is reducible but I can't really see how I have to proceed from here.

I've already read this question but it didn't really help me:
[Polynomial ring isomorphisms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2463027)

**EDIT: MY ATTEMPT** (after reading you suggestions)

Consider the morphism $\psi: \mathbb{R}[X] \to \frac{\mathbb{R}[X]}{(X^2)}$ defined by $\psi(P) = P(X + r)$ where $r$ is the double root of the polynomial $aX^2 + bX + c$.

It is easy to show that the kernel of $\psi$ is the ideal $(X-r)^2$.
An element of $\frac{\mathbb{R}[X]}{(X^2)}$ can be written as $P(X) + (X^2)$ where $P(X)$ is a polynomial of $\mathbb{R}[X]$. If we take $Q \in \mathbb{R}[X]$ such that $Q = P(X-r)$, then $\psi(Q) = Q(X+r) + (X^2) = P(X - r + r) + (X^2) = P(X) + (X^2) $. So $\psi$ is surjective and we conclude by using the first isomorphism theorem to find that

$$
R[X]/(aX^2 +bX + c) \eqsim  R[X]/ (X^2)
$$

Is this enough? or should I add the proof that $\psi$ is an morphism?

Comment: There is not much more to say, except that the 3rd ring isn't isomorphic to the 1st and 2nd, and to discuss (prime) ideals, nilpotents and zero divisors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that this question is essentially a duplicate, but I couldn't find an earlier question addressing it.

**Hint** If the discriminant $\Delta = b^2 - 4 a c$ is $0$, then the quadratic polynomial $aX^2 + bX + c$ has a double root and so can be written as $a (X - r)^2$ for some $r$. Assuming that $a \neq 0$, our ring is
$$\Bbb R[X] / (X - r)^2 ,$$
and by writing $Y := X - r$, we regard our ring as $$\Bbb R[Y] / (Y^2) .$$ It remains to describe this ring and in particular determine whether it is isomorphic to $\Bbb C$, to $\Bbb R \times \Bbb R$, or neither. (See also [dual numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_number) and well as [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3769831/155629) to a related question.)

Comment: Is it possible to solve this without ever having seen dual numbers?

Comment: @vitalmath Yes.

Comment: @vitalmath Yes, in fact sometimes the dual numbers are *defined* as the ring $\Bbb R[Y] / (Y^2)$, just as we can define the complex numbers as $\Bbb C := \Bbb R[X] / (X^2 + 1)$.